# SDR : Signal divided between the edges of the receiving window

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I'm using a SDR (specifically the RTL-SDR) to analyse the spectrum and i noticed a phenomena that does not seem logical.

The signal I want to capture is centred on 868.3 MHz and the central frequency of the SDR is centred on 869.3 MHz with a bandwidth of 2 MSamples. What I observed is that the 2 halves of the signal are displayed on both sides of the receiving window instead of just the half between 868.3MHz and 868.3MHz - 0.125MHZ ( as my signal bandwidth equals 125 KHz ) .

What do we call this phenomena and what is the explanation behind it ?

The first image is when the central frequency of the SDR is 868.3MHz
[image: Frequency display of the signal shown witout alteration]

The second image is when the central frequency ofthe SDR is 869.3MHz
[image: Frequency display of the signal divided in two halves]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's aliasing in its most classic form.

The anti-alias filter in your receiver isn't perfect, so that frequencies slightly outside of what you want to sample appear on the other end.